# Xdocument.element("Root") possible system.nullreferenceexception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm having an problem with my project when I try using XML to make an dropdown list.When I call `Xdocument.element("Root")` the resharped tell me that Possible 'System.NullReferenceException' and I don't know why 
here is my code

```
public JsonResult LoadProvince()
        {
            var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~/assets/client/data/Provinces_Data.xml"));
            var xElements = xmlDoc.Element("Root").Elements("Item").Where(x=>x.Attribute("type").Value=="province"); //here is the line I got the NullReferenceException

            var list = new List<ProvinceModel>();
            ProvinceModel province = null;
            foreach (var item in xElements)
            {
                province = new ProvinceModel();
                province.ID = int.Parse(item.Attribute("id").Value);
                province.Name = item.Attribute("value").Value;
                list.Add(province);
            }
            return Json(new
            {
                data=list,
                status = true
            });
        }
```

and here is the type of my XML file

```
<Root>
    <Item id="" type="" value=""></Item>
    <Item id="101" type="province" value="POI">
        <Item id="10151" type="district" value="ABC">
            <Item id="1015149" type="precinct" value="XYZ"/>
            <Item id="1015135" type="precinct" value="LKJ"/>
            <Item id="1015139" type="precinct" value="TYU"/>
</Root>
```

any idea to helping me out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your XML is invalid? I made a sample project and when I fixed your XML to the following:

```
<Root>
  <Item id="" type="" value=""/>
  <Item id="101" type="province" value="POI"/>
  <Item id="10151" type="district" value="ABC"/>
  <Item id="1015149" type="precinct" value="XYZ"/>
  <Item id="1015135" type="precinct" value="LKJ"/>
  <Item id="1015139" type="precinct" value="TYU"/>
</Root>
```

And when I executed the following code in a console app:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Provinces_Data.xml");
        var xElements = xmlDoc.Element("Root").Elements("Item").Where(x => x.Attribute("type").Value == "province"); 
        Console.WriteLine(xElements.First().ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I had no problems. ReSharper is nervous about the "xmlDoc.Element("Root")" but the program runs just fine.

Output if you want to know is:

```
<Item id="101" type="province" value="POI"/>
```

Plus you don't need .Element("Root"). It's better to do XDoc.Root.

Comment: really appreciate the help from you and now i'm gonna check my XML really careful to figured it out where the bug come from

Comment: You're welcome. You also don't need XElement("Root"), see update. I also advice you to give your xml elements meaningful names. Like Provinces and Province.

Comment: This answer is completely missing the point! The content of the XML itself has nothing to do with Resharper's warning. And it works because this is just a warning that in this case is irrelevant. Like #pollikop, I also wonder why Resharper gives this warning in the first place, as nowhere in the documentation of XDocument.Load it says that it can return null...

Comment: @Arnon 1) pollikop asked a different question in a comment he made at march 18 at 13:59. I see now how this is confusion, so maybe pollikop could update his original question with the second question. 2) So the actual answer to his original question about ReSharper is below this one (the answer of march 18 at 13:49). To answer your specific comment. It's not about XDocument.Load, it's about .Element("Root") which could potentially be null.

Answer (score 0):

Because ReSharper doesn't know exactly what you are doing and only detects that you are calling methods on objects that could be null if the method call higher up the chain returned nothing. That is all. You can ignore it. Or use the conditional null operator (?) if you want.

Comment: unfortunately the xElements is return **null** when xmlDoc return exactly value of XML file and that the problem and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: This is a totally different question.

Comment: sorry for my bad communication but can you help me out ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Resharper is jut trying to be helpful. It doesn't necessarily mean you have done something wrong.

`XDocument.Element` *may* return null if it doesn't find the element specified. Resharper doesn't actually know what the XML file looks like. It's trying to tell you that you're not handling the case where it *may* return null, which would result in a `NullReferenceException`.

If you can guarantee that it will never null-reference, then you can ignore the warning. If it's possible for someone to upload an XML file and you just assume it's well structured, then you might want to handle that case, like:

```
 var root = document.Element("Root");
 if (root == null)
 {
     //handle null here
 }
```